# form input box to download files

Tags: php

Developing a school website in WordPress and need to upload Progress Report of students in the server in pdf format. File name of Progress report will be the Admission number of the students (Eg. 123.pdf). When students enter their Admission number in the input box, they should get their progress report file downloaded. As of now using below form box to redirect to file url.

```
<script>
function process()
{
var url="http://demo.websign.in/" + 
document.getElementById("url").value;
location.href=url;
return false;
}
</script>
<form onSubmit="return process();">
ENTER YOUR ADMISSION NUMBER: <input type="text" name="url" id="url"> 
<input type="submit" value="DOWNLOAD">
</form>
```

Any help as I am a theme developer and no much knowledge in coding?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is not meant to teach basics - you must learn them on your own. Please come back if you have a specific question.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need form tag to download file. Also instead of type "submit" use "button". The js you need is something like this:

```js
function myFunction()
  {
   var downloadUrl = document.getElementById("url").value;
   document.getElementById("downlod").href = downloadUrl + '.pdf';
  }
```

```html
<div>
   <label>ENTER YOUR ADMISSION NUMBER:</label> <input type="text" name="url" id="url" onkeypress="myFunction()"> 
   <a href="foo" id="downlod" download><span>Download</span></a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. While entering 3 digits in the box only 2 digits are added to the url

Comment: Ooopss... I missed that. You should use the onkeyup event instead of onkeypress. Something like this: <input type="text" name="url" id="url" onkeyup="myFunction()">

Comment: Thank you once again. One more small issue. file is located in the url  www.example.in/example.pdf but code is requesting the file from the download page that is from www.example.in/downloadpage/example.pdf

Comment: You need to modify the js so that href ="/path/file.pdf. Note the prefix "/" without domain name. I guess in your case the required script is: document.getElementById("downlod").href = '/' + downloadUrl + '.pdf'; also plz mark my answer if if found it useful ;)

Comment: Thank you Amit. My problem solved. I am developing simple wordpress themes without any code knowledge and when customers demanding new requirements, I have no other option than asking and getting help from you like people. I am interested in programming. can you suggest any online courses to learn basics? Any way thanks a lot. I am from Kerala, India. In return I can help you for anything if you are coming to kerala any time.

Comment: Thanks & welcome, you can start basic with w3school and then practice, practice, and practice:codecource, jsfiddle, codeacadmy and like other hackthon.... Be motivated and be engaged with community(stackexchange, github...);This is the only hardest and first step, rest...  no one can teach better than yourself